# OSX Sierra 10.12.1, Excel 2016: Cleaning Excel data after converting from PDF

Tags: macos, pdf, microsoft-excel-2016

I needed to compile data from a PDF into an Excel spreadsheet for further analysis. Each PDF page begins with "Unclassified" at the top and a row with the column headings. I used NitroPDF for the conversion from PDF to Excel (pdftoexcelonline.com/en/).

[PDF of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY1uS.png)

It seemed to work great and I proceeded to convert thousands of entries. However, upon review I noticed that each new PDF page seems to have created a new column in my Excel sheet. [Excel columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y599P.png)

Questions: I have thousands of entries.

1. Is there any way to remove these extra columns while preserving data integrity and formatting?

OR... 2. Is this a task better handled during the initial conversion from a PDF to an Excel file and, if so, can someone recommend how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the PDF input file?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I ended up converting to MS Word then to Excel which solved my problem. Here is the link, its to the US CENTCOM FOIA website (your browser will give you security warnings when you click on it, all .mil sites do for some reason): https://www6.centcom.mil/foia_rr/FOIA_RR.asp?Path=/5%20USC%20552(a)(2)(D)Records&Folder=MDR%2014-53